How to create environment variable from JSON values in GitHub actions
I am using GitHub Issue form to capture few inputs from User. Once form is submitted, I am using JSON parser to retrieve the form inputs.
When I run echo ${{ steps.parser.outputs.json }}, I am able to view the JSON output (displayed below). However, I have 3 inputs that I would like to pass as an environment variable for next job.
My current issue is, when I run Test step, I can view JSON for $SOURCE_BRANCH (Which matches with the output of the code, this not not what I am looking for).
I would like to pass values for each Keys as an environment variable for next action. Is there any actions in Marketplace or any easier approach to solve the issue?
My YML file:
name: JSON

on:
  issues:
    types: [opened]

jobs:
  issue-retrieval:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    permissions:
      issues: write
      contents: read
      packages: read

    steps:
      - name: Parse Issue
        id: parser
        uses: issue-ops/parser@v4.0.0
        with:
          body: ${{ github.event.issue.body }}

      - name: Output Issue JSON
        id: output-issue
        run: |
          echo ${{ steps.parser.outputs.json }}

          # Set environment variables
          echo "SOURCE_BRANCH=$(echo ${{ steps.parser.outputs.json }})" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "TARGET_BRANCH=target_branch" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "FOLDERS=folders_double_quoted_comma_separated_within" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          
      - name: Test
        run: |
          echo $SOURCE_BRANCH
          echo $TARGET_BRANCH
          echo $FOLDERS
          

JSON output from echo:
 source_branch:DEV target_branch:UAT folders_double_quoted_comma_separated_within:_No response_ contact_details:_No response_


You need to extract the json values and assign each value:
- name: Output Issue JSON
  id: output-issue
  run: |
    echo ${{ steps.parser.outputs.json }}

    # Set environment variables
    echo "SOURCE_BRANCH=$(echo '${{ steps.parser.outputs.json }}' | jq -r '.source_branch')" >> $GITHUB_ENV
    echo "TARGET_BRANCH=$(echo '${{ steps.parser.outputs.json }}' | jq -r '.target_branch')" >> $GITHUB_ENV
    echo "FOLDERS=$(echo '${{ steps.parser.outputs.json }}' | jq -r '.folders_double_quoted_comma_separated_within')" >> $GITHUB_ENV

